# Outlook 2013 not sending meeting replies with harmon.ie enabled

Tags: outlook-addin, harmon.ie

When the harmon.ie plugin is enabled and I reply to a meeting request, the e-mail stays in the Outbox and displays the following bounce message:

```
Remote Server returned '554 5.6.0 STOREDRV.Submit.Exception:TextConvertersException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message data truncated TextConvertersException: data truncated'
```

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Did you have a chance to disable the harmon.ie add-in? Does it work correctly? If so, did you have a chance to contact harmon.ie developers?

Answer (score 0):

Please use cached mode in Outlook in such case. Similar issues have been reported out of harmon.ie, while this is not the case on your side this issue the root cause, see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/99603591-73d8-4e07-9457-b1aaaf95d93e/undeliverable-response-received-when-accepting-meeting-requests?forum=exchangesvrclients)

----- Jean